# Reading xml document in java application

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've been doing a lot of solutions, but noone does it work. How can i print this XML code in java. The main problem is how can I print value xml:lang.

```
<resource xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/ofbiz-properties.xsd">
<property key="hour.plural">
    <value xml:lang="ar">ساعات</value>
    <value xml:lang="de">Stunden</value>

<value xml:lang="pl">oglądaj</value></property></resource>
```

It's the resource class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="resource")
public class resource {

    private String property;
    private String value;

    public root(String property, String value) {
        this.property = property;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return property + value;
    }
}
```

And that's the main class

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import project1.resource;
    public class xmlread {

        public static void main(String... arg) throws Exception {
            File file = new File("C:DateTimeLabels.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(resource.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            resource Resource = (resource) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(Resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your attempts please, even if they didn't work, so we can point out whether there's any error in there.

Comment: To just print it, you can use a simple string and write it to `System.out`. I suppose your question is more complex. Please [edit] your question, and explain exactly what your input and output must be and where your difficulty lies, and the research you have done.

Comment: Your question contradicts itself.  Reading and printing are not the same thing.  Which are you actually asking about: reading or printing?  Also, I agree with Michael.  If you showed us your code we would have a better idea of what you are trying to do, and what you may have done wrong.

Comment: I've edited my question guys.

Comment: I assure you you have not edited your question

Comment: Now should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="resource")
public class resource {

    private String property;
    private String value;

    public root(String property, String value) {
        this.property = property;
        this.value = value;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return property + value;
    }
}`
```

Add this to your resource class, should help the marshaller find the exact properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one value, so for the sake of the `<value>` elements, you need to define a list of values.

The  elements are contained inside the  elements, so you have a nested structure here. That means you need a Property class contained in your Resource class, and your Property class need to contain a Value class.

You need to bind the key attribute and the xml:lang attributes.

Here is an example of Jaxb-annotated classes that does most of the work to map to your XML format. Complete as you need.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Resource {
  private Property property = new Property();

  public Property getProperty() {
    return property;
  }

  public void setProperty(Property property) {
    this.property = property;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Resource.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

    Resource resource = new Resource();
    resource.getProperty().setKey("hour.plural");
    resource.getProperty().getValues().add(new Value("fr"));
    resource.getProperty().getValues().add(new Value("it"));
    resource.getProperty().getValues().add(new Value("ru"));

    marshaller.marshal(resource, System.out);
  }

}

class Property {
  private String key;

  private List<Value> values = new ArrayList<>();

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "value")
  public List<Value> getValues() {
    return values;
  }

  public void setValues(List<Value> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

}

class Value {
  private String lang;

  public Value() {

  }

  public Value(String lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getLang() {
    return lang;
  }

  public void setLang(String lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
  }

}
```